# How do you mitigate proposal-number overflow attacks in Byzantine Paxos?

Tags: algorithm, distributed-system, paxos

I've been doing a lot of research into Paxos recently, and one thing I've always wondered about, I'm not seeing any answers to, which means I have to ask.

Paxos includes an increasing proposal number (and possibly also a separate round number, depending on who wrote the paper you're reading). And of course, two would-be leaders can get into duels where each tries to out-increment the other in a vicious cycle. But as I'm working in a Byzantine, P2P environment, it makes me what to do about proposers that would attempt to set the proposal number extremely high - for example, the maximum 32-bit or 64-bit word.

How should a language-agnostic, platform-agnostic Paxos-based protocol deal with integer maximums for proposal number and/or round number? Especially intentional/malicious cases, which make the modular-arithmetic approach of overflowing back to 0 a bit unattractive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've read, I think this is still an open question that isn't addressed in literature.

[Byzantine Proposer Fast Paxos](http://www.sysnet.ucsd.edu/sysnet/miscpapers/ByPropFastPaxos.pdf) addresses denial of service, but only of the sort that would delay message sending through attacks not related to flooding with incrementing (proposal) counters.

Having said that, integer overflow is probably the least of your problems. Instead of thinking about integer overflow, you might want to consider membership attacks first (via DoS). Learning about membership after consensus from several nodes may be a viable strategy, but probably still vulnerable to [Sybil attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybil_attack) at some level.

Another strategy may be to incorporate some [proof-of-work system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) for proposals to limit the flood of requests. However, it's difficult to know what to use this as a metric to balance against (for example, free currency when you mine the block chain in Bitcoin). It really depends on what type of system you're trying to build. You should consider the value of information in your system, then create a proof of work system that requires slightly more cost to circumvent.

However, once you have the ability to slow down a proposal counter, you still need to worry about integer maximums in any system with a high number of (valid) operations. You should have a strategy for number wrapping or a multiple precision scheme in place where you can clearly determine how many years/decades your network can run without encountering trouble without blowing out a fixed precision counter. If you can determine that your system will run for 100 years (or whatever) without blowing out your fixed precision counter, even with malicious entities, then you can choose to simplify things.

On another (important) note, the system model used in most papers doesn't reflect everything that makes a real-life implementation practical ([Raft](https://ramcloud.stanford.edu/wiki/download/attachments/11370504/raft.pdf) is a nice exception to this). If anything, some authors are guilty of creating a system model that is designed to avoid a hard problem that they haven't found an answer to. So, if someone says that X will solve everything, please be aware they they only mean that it solves everything in the very specific system model that they defined. On the other side of this, you should consider that the system model is closely tied to a statement that says "Y is impossible". A nice example to explain this concept is the completely asynchronous message passing of the [Ben-Or consensus algorithm](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/aguilera/benorproof-dc.pdf) which uses nondeterminism in the system model's state machine to avoid the limits specified by the [FLP impossibility result](http://macs.citadel.edu/rudolphg/csci604/ImpossibilityofConsensus.pdf) (which specifies that consensus requires partially asynchronous message passing when the system model's state machine is deterministic).

So, you should continue to consider the "impossible" after you read a proof that says it can't be done. Nancy Lynch did a [nice writeup](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/tds/papers/Lynch/podc89.pdf) on this concept.

I guess what I'm really saying is that a good solution to your question doesn't really exist yet. If you figure it out, please publish it (or let me know if you find an existing paper).

Comment: Excellent answer! Unfortunately, I still don't have an answer to this. However, thanks to unrelated protocol simplifications, I've managed to entirely avoid the problem altogether, using a model that is only Paxos-like, and doesn't require a counter at all. Probably a good real-life example of "creating a system model that is designed to avoid a hard problem that they haven't found an answer to," but there are other benefits as well. Simple is always better, if it can be made to work.

Comment: Great answer! I've been wondering if proof-of-work can be used for leader election in non-byzantine context? I also suspect there are blockchain like solutions to this problem. I wonder - is there a byzantine generalization of raft?